# jquery content displayed as text on the web page

Tags: java, jquery

Greetings all: Here is my simple code, Why is my javascript showing up as text on my page? any help would greatly appreciated, also any tips would be appreciated. thank you in advance

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

        <title>My web page</title>

        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />   
        <!-- this is the script file which is displayed as text --> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= request.getContextPath()%> 
        <%=/javascript/%>js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js?version=<%= Version.getVersion() 
        %>"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment if I could. I’ve created a fiddle with your code and the script tag is not being shown in the output.
I added a `<span>test</span>` to show the output is working.
You could provide more information about your code to see if something else is causing the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/51Ls7tz8/